# Can I vertex paint with an image?

Tags: vertex-paint

I am vertex painting using Cycles, & I have set up nodes to plug the vertex colors into a shader & it paints on & works fine, renders etc, looks as expected. But vertex painting gives a brush color choice only - Question - is it possible to use an image bitmap instead of the brush colors? Or - is vertex painting only for colors? I made a material with an image, unwrapped my object's surface, but so far I can't find a way to use this image as the color source (apart from just putting this material onto the selected surface area).

Comment: I answered the question that is in the title ; however, I suspect your method is wrong, and I can't really understand your second question. What exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: As thibsert said, Properties Panel-->Brush setting lets you select a texture. The brush color/color swatch is only used as an overlay. Select white if you don't want any overlay.

Answer (score 2):

Under the brush settings, in Texture, click New. In the properties panel, in Texture/Image click Open, then locate your picture file. You can now use the picture as a brush.